# Replacing values in column not working pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy

my sample data set:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = {'ID': ['A',0,0,1,'A',1],
'ID1':['Yes','Yes','No','No','Yes','Yes']}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

my real data set is read in from an excel file, the column 'ID1' contains 'Yes' or 'No'. the column 'ID' contains 1, 0 and 'A'.
I want to:

1. For column 'ID1' I want to replace 'Yes' as 1 and 'No' as 0.
2. for column 'ID' I want to replace 'A' as 0

I tried following ways

```
# The values didn't change
df['ID1']=df['ID1'].replace(['Yes', 'No'], [1, 0])
# Or, The values didn't change
df['ID1']=df['ID1'].replace(['Yes', 'No'], [1, 0],inplace='ignore')
# Or,  it turns 'A' to 'nan'
df['ID'] = df['ID'].map({1: 1, 0: 0, 'A':0})
 # OR, it turns 'A' to 'nan'
df['ID'] = df['ID'].map({1: 1, 0: 0, 'A':0}, na_action=None)
```

*My code works perfectly if you run my sample data set code to get the sample data set, which converts the Series into DF*, **but it doesn't work with my real data set which I read in from an excel file.** I searched online but couldn't figure out why. these columns from my real data set are object type, i tried converting to string but still doesn't work.

**edit:**

my code for reading my real data set:

```
path =os.chdir(r"S:\path")

df1 = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx',skiprows=[0]) 

df1['ID']=df1['ID'].str.strip()
df1['ID'] = df1['ID'].map({'1': 1, '0': 0, 'A':0}, na_action=None)

df1['ID1']=df1['ID1'].str.strip()
df1['ID1']=df1['ID1'].replace(['Yes', 'No'], [1, 0])

df1.head()
Out[55]: 
    ID1   ID
0    1  NaN
1    1  NaN
2    1  NaN
3    1  0.0
4    1  NaN
```

I have uploaded my file online, please check this link : https://filebin.ca/3UAh5051Psnv/test.xlsx

Comment: You'd need to give details about your actual usecase where it doesn't work, it'd be difficult to figure out what's and why something is not working on a sample that is working well. :-) Could you show your actual `df.head()`?

Comment: @John Galt   please see my edit, somehow it's reading in these columns as none and nan... what is going on

Comment: Hard to say what the problem is when you haven't shared the structure of the sheet and how you're calling `pd.read_excel`.

Comment: @cmaher please see my edit

Comment: try to do this before using `.replace()`: `df['ID1']=df['ID1'].str.strip()`

Comment: @MaxU please see my edit, it worked for ID1 but the '1's in column 'ID' became NaN and 'A' became NaN as well. i tried without the .strip(), then everything became NaN...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clean up `ID1` and `ID` columns:

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype(str).str.strip().map({'1': 1, '0': 0, 'A':0}, na_action=None)
df['ID1'] = df['ID1'].str.strip().replace(['Yes', 'No'], [1, 0])
```

Result:

```
In [234]: df
Out[234]:
    ID1  ID
0     1   1
1     1   1
2     1   1
3     1   0
4     1   1
5     1   1
6     1   0
7     1   1
8     1   1
9     1   1
10    1   1
11    1   1
12    1   1
13    1   0
14    1   1
15    1   1
16    1   0
17    1   1
18    1   1
19    1   1
20    1   1
21    1   1
22    1   1
23    1   1
24    1   1
25    1   1
26    1   1
27    1   1
28    1   1
29    1   1
30    1   1
```

Comment: sorry for the confusing comments. what I mean is when I do column ID . str.strip()  all of the 1's became 'NaN'.  so I don't even have to continue further because that's not right.  if I don't do that step and do pd.to_numeric() then the 'A's became 'NaN'...

Comment: can you upload your excel file (or a reproducible part of it) somewhere and post here a link to it?

Comment: thanks! please check this link:  https://filebin.ca/3UAh5051Psnv/test.xlsx